# What is the form of טבו in מה טבו אהליך יעקב?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, parashat-balak

In the verse ([Num 24,5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.24.5?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&with=Targum&lang2=he)):

> מַה־טֹּבוּ אֹהָלֶיךָ יַעֲקֹב מִשְׁכְּנֹתֶיךָ יִשְׂרָאֵל׃

What's the meaning of טובו, could it not be written מה טובים אהליך יעקב?

Comment: In Shir hashirim there's מה יפו פעמיך and מה טבו דודיך מיין and מה יפו דודיך

Comment: As all Targumim (to Aramaic) inc English translate it as an adjective, why not say it's just a different/misspelled form of טובים just as all the Examples of DoubleAA?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word טֹּבוּ is a verb (not an adjective like טוֹב), conjugated for past (perfect aspect). Compare the conjugation of אֹרוּ ([I Samuel 14:29](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Samuel.14.29?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). This is the conjugation normally used to describe a current state.

See the entry in the Even Shoshan dictionary:

[image]

Some more examples:

> **מַה־יָּפִית֙** **וּמַה־נָּעַ֔מְתְּ** אַהֲבָ֖ה בַּתַּֽעֲנוּגִֽים׃
>
> **How fair you are**, **how beautiful**! O Love, with all its rapture!

([Song of Songs 7:7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Song_of_Songs.7.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi))

> **מָֽה־אָהַ֥בְתִּי** תוֹרָתֶ֑ךָ כָּל־הַ֝יּ֗וֹם הִ֣יא שִׂיחָתִֽי׃
>
> **O how I love** Your teaching! It is my study all day long.

([Psalms 119:97](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Psalms.119.97?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

Comment: I'm not convinced. It seems more plausible to say it's just a different/misspelled form of טובים than say that טובו is a verb. Can you find a translation that uses a verb instead? And theoretically, how do you prove a meaning if not its earliest translations?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87595/discussion-between-b-a-and-al-berko).